# Lycra Printer- Elastic Fabric Printer

Tags: print-production, hardware-recommendation, hardware

I am looking for a printer that prints on Lycra material (This is like swimwear material and also sportswear material).
Does someone maybe know this type of printer? Where I can find it and what is the name of this printer?
Please help :-)

Comment: Hi Ledine, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I think the usual way to print that kind of material is screen printing.
The inks used, should be stretchy. I don't have experience in screen printing Lycra, but I believe you can mix an additive to plastisol inks to make them more stretchable.

If you are looking for a machine you could start looking for screen printing equipment

I know there are printers that can print directly on the material using screenprint inks. As far as I know it is quite expensive and usually for prototypes and one-offs.